# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap`

Tags: java, json, jackson

From one project I send data to another project.
I have my data in LinkedHashMap.
When I send, I convert map in Json:
`objectMapper.writeValueAsString(visitToInsurer)`
 
 
When I try to convert json value to map, I do:

```
T getJsonMessage(byte[] body) throws IOException {
  return objectMapper.readValue(body, resolveGenericType());
}   
Class<T> resolveGenericType() {
   Class<?>[] tClass = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(getClass(), SomeClass.class);
   return (Class<T>) tClass[0];//here i get interface of Map
}
```

And then I got an error:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value` 
  
 
`('{"id":1,"id2":2,"bDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.032087","eDate":"9999-12-31T00:00","cDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.032087","use":"1","act":true,"in":0,"vDt":null,"vDt2":null,"dCheck":null,"vFlag":true,"nFlag":false,"vFlag2":false,"nFlag2":false,"uFlag":true,"rFlag":false,"dId":1,"it":1,"rId":1,"rCode":"1","iNum":"1","iAb":"OOO\"TEST-1 \"TEST\"","dId3":2,"dId4":2,"dName":"Test","vId5":null,"vId6":null,"pDt7":null,"pDt8":null,"vDt9":null,"vDt10":null,"wCnt":null,"dId8":null,"dId9":null,"dName10":null,"dName11":"Test","cReason":null,"vd12":null,"vId13":null,"vNum14":null,"vDate15":null,"act":null,"rLst":[{"id":1,"id2":2,"bDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.236460","eDate":"9999-12-31T00:00","cDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.236460","user":"1","vId":1,"vId2":1,"dId":2,"dId2":2,"dName":"TTT","pDt":null,"pDt2":null,"vDt":null,"vDt2":null,"cBegin":"2020-05-04T00:00:00","cEnd":"2020-05-05T00:00:00","cNum":"111","amount":0,"amount2":0,"prem":0,"f":0,"pen":0,"dId5":1,"dName6":"Test","aFlag":false,"rId":11,"rCode":"11","cNum":0,"dId7":1,"pId8":null,"pId9":null,"act":null}],"vCard":{"id":1,"id2":1,"bDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.032087","eDate":"9999-12-31T00:00","cDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.032087","user":"1","act":true,"invalid":0,"rId":1,"rCode":"1","iName":"TEST \"TEST \"TEST\"","iName2":"TEST\"TEST \"TEST\"","rNum":"1","in5":"1","k77":"1","og77":"11","rBegin":"2009-09-28T00:00:00","inDate":"2009-09-28T00:00:00","outDate":null,"phone":null,"localAddress":"TEST","email":null,"iStatus":"State","sCode":"1","iCode":"1","oCode":"1","cBegin5":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","pName":null,"pName2":null,"pReg":null,"action":null,"vList":[{"id":1,"id2":"1","cCode":"1","vId":1,"vId2":1,"bDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.032087","eDate":"9999-12-31T00:00","cDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.032087","user":"1","actual":true,"rId":1,"rCode":"1","came":"ТTEST","cPhone":null,"cP":"TEST","action":null}],"vList2":[]},"vList3":[{"id":1,"id2":1,"bDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.095369","eDate":"9999-12-31T00:00","cDate":"2020-04-04T16:22:45.095369","user":"1","actual":true,"vId":1,"vId":1,"tNum":"1","surname":"TEST","name":"TEST","pat":"TEST","pName2":"TEST","phone":null,"kId":1,"kId2":1,"vChecks":"TEST","nFlag":false,"vFlag":true,"nFlag2":false,"vFlag2":false,"action":null}],"vList5":[]}')`

UPDATE: 
Thank you all. Problem was in my code where I send message from producer to subscriber. I try to send json string in field for object, not in field for json string.

```
public class ProducerMsg {
    private String body;
    private Object objectBody;
}
```

So in dependency it doesnt't work because think that it is already Map(and I send String in which is Map)

Comment: What exactly are `T` and `tClass[0]`? Anyways, I would recommend to check if `objectMapper.readValue(body, java.util.Map.class)` works.

Comment: I can't change this, because it is a dependency.

Comment: If you can't change the code, you can at least copy/write and run similar code. I tried to call `readValue(body, java.util.Map.class)` for my mapper and it worked. It means that JSON text is valid.
So the problem is caused most probably by `resolveGenericType()` - I suppose, it returns something different from either java.util.Map or java.util.LinkedHashMap. That's why I asked you to specify what values have T and tClass[0]. Can you provide such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please refer below code


 public class JsonToMapDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String json = "{\"name\":\"Akshay\",\"age\":\"23\"}";
    convertJsonToMap(json);

}

private static void convertJsonToMap(String jsonString) {
    try {

        Map<String, Object> personMap =  new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

/*
If we need LinkedHashMap Object

LinkedHashMap personMap =  (LinkedHashMap) new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
*/

```
        System.out.println(personMap);

    } 
    catch (JsonGenerationException e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 

    } 
    catch (JsonMappingException e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

```
code output

{name=Akshay, age=23}
```

Comment: In what constructor? I want convert json to Map<String, Object>.

Comment: I can't do like this: `new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Map.class)`. This `return objectMapper.readValue(body, resolveGenericType());` is from dependency.

Comment: which dependency are you using .can you show me your POJO class

Comment: This is an internal dependency of the company I work for.

Comment: And I try to convert json string to Map, not to POJO class.

Comment: I understood that you are converting json string to map .Sometimes what happens is in your model or pojo class deserializer cannot find correct mapping for that particular field then this error arises so you need consructor or setter,getter property for that field